# what is better: passing args between functions or working with static objects?

Tags: c#, coding-style

in the [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) book there's an opinion that the best practice is to work with functions with no args passed to and from. So my question is what makes more sense, to work with functions that pass args to each other, or void functions that share and manipulate static objects?

Examples:

**Option 1.**

```
public List<MyThing> FunctionA(List <MyThing> myThings){

myThings.Add(SomeBlah);

return myThings;     
}

public void FunctionB(){

List<MyThing> myThings = new List<MyThing>();

myThings = InitiateThingsOrWhatever();

List<MyThing> myChangedThings = FunctionA(myThings);  
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
private static List<MyThing> _myThings = new List<MyThing>();

public static List<MyThing> MyThings{
get { return _myThing; }
set { _myThing = value; }
}

public void SomeFunction(){

FunctionA();
FunctionB();
}

public void FunctionA(){

MyThings = YadaYadaStuff();     
}

public void FunctionB(){

var showMyChangedThings = MyThings; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best forum for "opinion" based questions. This question will most likely be closed.

Comment: Try `programmers.SE`, and frame it as "What are the advantages / disadvantages?" and you might get the answer you want.  A "What is better" can't be answered without opinions.

Comment: While the question looks like "what is you opinion" I believe it mainly misunderstanding of recommendation in the book...

Comment: "Dear Option 2 programmer, I hate you. Tim"

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for here, it would be better off in the general programming area.

Comment: you should remove oop from the tags :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing arguments is significantly better than using shared static data.

I believe you've misunderstood (or read too directly) the recommendation. There is no recommendation to use static shared data instead of passing arguments in that book to my knowledge.

The recommendation is to minimize number of arguments passed to member functions. Often you can transform "a lot of arguments" into a class and than provide method with no arguments to execute original function.

Sample of transforming some arguments into an object:

```
int MultiplySome(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
{ 
   return arg1 * arg2 * arg3;
}
```

Can be transformed into an object with method that takes less arguments:

```
class MultiplySomeClass
{  
   public int First;
   public int Second;

   int MultiplyBy(int arg3) { return First * Second * arg3;}
}
```

And call changed from:

```
var result = MultiplySome(4,5,6);

var multiplyHelper = new MultiplySomeClass { First = 4, Second = 5 };
var result = multiplyHelper.MultiplyBy(6);
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

Uncle Bob was discussing the interaction between functions within a single class in the passage you are referencing. He was recommending that you take the data commonly passed between those functions and move it to be private attributes of the object. So this is not creating global data, it is all encapsulated within the class. The static data/function approach is polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

static is never good and the design in option 2 is unusable in practically any software, what if you have two object of the same class that have to mantain different state?